# Dynamics 365 on premise Update

Tags: dynamics-crm

Dear Community members,

hope you all have a wonderful day.

i have a question regarding the update from 8.2 into the latest version, i allready started to install the update starting from 8.2.5.0004 to the next one which is 8.2.5.0004 then i thought why not skip the minor updates and jupm into the latest version of 8 which is 8.2.28.11 and it works with no issue. so my question is is it possiple to update into the latest version in one step, i mean going from 8.2.28.11 to 9.1.20.11 or is it going to cuse any issue.

this is my first time dealing witn on premise version of D365 so pease advise me on this matter.

thanks in advance, and have a good day.

the update starting from 8.2.5.0004 to the next one which is 8.2.5.0004 then i thought why not skip the minor updates and jupm into the latest version of 8 which is 8.2.28.11 and it works with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

We did just upgrade from 8.2 to 9.1.19. We did it to a separate dynamics server with the database import wizard.

If you want to do it in-place, make sure you have snapshots from  the server and backup of mscrm_config and the organization databases. And your server and sqlserver should meet the requirements of dynamics 9.1.

Feel free to ask if you have further questions.